# How to use bitwise operators for in a whole row or column?

Tags: c++, opencv, row, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

I am looking image processing with c++ opencv nowadays. And I need to make 'or' each column or row of a matrix. for example

```
A =[1 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0];

I need to take for row 
Ans = [1 1 1 0];

for column
Ans =[1;
      0;
      1];
```

I searched it for long time but methinks I will not be able to find it. Please Help me !

Comment: Just use `std::transform`?

Comment: Are you looking to do this for a huge matrix and distributed across many processors, using OpenCV? Or are you looking to do this using standard C++ for a standard data type? What is the data type of the matrix anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is split into rows and cols as:

```
const int rows = 3; 
const int cols = 4;
int A[rows][cols] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
```

then you may use:

```
int ansrow[cols], anscol[rows];
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++ ){
  ansrow[i] = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < rows; j++ ){
    ansrow[i] |= A[i][j];
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
  anscol[i] = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < cols; j++ ){
    anscol[i] |= A[i][j];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

given, that Ans_row is a cv::Mat and Ans_row.cols== mat.cols you could easily write:

```
Mat a = Ans_row | mat.row(i); //expects: Ans_row.cols== mat.cols, Ans_row.rows==1
```

and:

```
Mat b = And_col | mat.col(i); //expects: Ans_col.rows== mat.rows, Ans_row.cols==1
```

Answer (score 0):

rgb[1] is my matrix,

```
cv::Size s = rgb[1].size();

bitwise_or(rgb[1].col(1),rgb[1].col(2),asd1);
for(i = 3;i<s.width;i++)
{
   bitwise_or(rgb[1].col(i),asd1,asd1);     
}
```

at first, I wanted to do this job without any loop, like matlab any() command. But I think it is impossible in c++. or I couldnt find.

Thank you for all answers.